# Type '"Project Name"."Dataset_tableadapter".TableAdapterManager' is not defined

Tags: vb.net

I Was Developing a very bassice vb.net project by using vb.net 2010 and my database is ms Access 2007. in my project it's having 8 database which are showing informatation in each form and every thing was working fine has i have already created many project of this kind.But When i was nearly done with project and just adding some Splash Screen in it suddenly there were 102 Errors Saying "Type '"Project Name"."Dataset_tableadapter".TableAdapterManager' is not defined."

I tryed refreshing my database conection, relinking  my database,and checked every name of table adapter and the name showen in code... every thing was ok yet there was same error....

I Searched on google about the same but there was nothing useful. All were just asking to check name of table adapter or of database etc etc......

Comment: Did you make a backup? What if you remove you're splash screen?mybe you removed somthing.but dificult to say if we don't see code.

Comment: I Don't Have Any Backup..... I tryed Removing Splash Screen But Problem was still There And For Code I Don't Know Which Part Of Code To be Posted...........

Comment: Friend WithEvents Main_HistoryTableAdapter5 As test5.Main_Nagpur_DataSetTableAdapters.Main_HistoryTableAdapter
Friend WithEvents TableAdapterManager5 As test5.Main_Nagpur_DataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager
Friend WithEvents Main_Vapi_DataSet As test5.Main_Vapi_DataSet

Comment: This is party of my code in which error is showen..... And this error is in every table adapter of every form and "test5" is my project name

Comment: Sorry can't say for sure.1 rule always make backups.I'am just guesing but you can try"1 make a backup.readd the data adapter and or adapter manager.just make sure you use the same name.or the name that is needed."

Comment: When I was New in vb.net i used to take backup but now i am normally able to solve many of my codeing related problem. but this time it's not in the code that i have typed it's in automaticlly generated code... And i just tryed readding of data adapter with same name but didn't work.... :-(

Comment: It would be interesting to see the actual error message because the approximation that you've provided suggests an error in your code, but the method suggests a fault in the auto-generated code.  I'd suggest deleeting your typed DataSet altogether and generating a new one.  If all the names are the same then any code referencing the old DataSet should simply work.  You will have to add DataSets and table adapters back to forms in the designer though.

Comment: By the way, you don't have eight databases, or at least I certainly hope you don't.  You should have one database with eight tables.

Comment: I am planing to Start from Begning And i am developing software from my Office and i have 8 branches of offfice and i don't want other branch to see data of other branch so i have that that will ask to select there branch at the time of first use and then tere branch related option will remain there and all other buttons visible property will become no and data base will get deleted so i have 8 database for each branch... and also it has 8 database so that head office can see data of all the branches by entring password....

Comment: Actual Error Msg....     Error   49 Type 'test5.Main_Vapi_DataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager' is not defined. C:\Users\ITC\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\test5\test5\New Entry in Vadodara Main.Designer.vb 899 47 test5

Comment: Actual Error Msg 2..... Error   73 Type 'test5.Main_Vapi_DataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager' is not defined. C:\Users\ITC\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\test5\test5\Vadodara.Designer.vb 187 39 test5
  There are 102 Error like this and when i delete error code another error shows up in rest of the forms

Comment: I Just Created project from starting and added all the forms and database from old project and there were no error..... so problem is solved........